# Running code in Eclipse with additional input

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

In my CS class we use the terminal to run our codes, using the javac to cimpile and java to run.
In my current assignment I'm receiving inputs from a file. The name of the file is given when inputing the command in the CMD (terminal) like this:
"java -cp mypath\class **text.txt**"
using this code:

```
if (args.length != 1) {
        final String msg = "Usage: EmployeePay name_of_input file";
        System.err.println(msg);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    }
    final String inputFileName = args[0];
    final File input = new File (inputFileName); 
    final Scanner in = new Scanner (input);
```

When running this with Eclipse, it throws the Exception. Is there a way in eclipse to do this command "java -cp mypath\class **text.txt**" without changing or adding anything to the code itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Run`/`Run configurations...`, then select your "run  instance" in the left, then select the `Arguments` tab and finally enter your **text.txt** into the `Program arguments` field. Click `Apply` and repeat that for the other "run instances" if any.

You may click `Run` if you want to run your project, but do not forget tto click `Apply` beforehand...